# Locally accessed react app does not do API call [CRA]

Tags: reactjs

I am using CRA to setup my react app.

I want to ask, how do I make a locally accessed react app do API call.
To explain my question, I can only do it by describing it.

So currently, my machine has 192.168.1.2 as its IP.
My backend server is running on 192.168.1.2:3000 (if i hit 192.168.1.2:3000/customers on browser I get the json response)
My frontend is running on 192.168.1.2:3001

If i open http://localhost:3001 or http://192.168.1.2:3001 from my laptop browser, all components render, it will render the Loading component and then not long after the list will render. (If i check my backend server, i can see that my server receives GET request)

However if I open http://192.168.1.2:3001 from my phone, all components render, but it is stuck at Loading component. When I check my backend server, it receives no request at all. So from what I can see is that by accessing my react app locally outside from the hosting machine, the app won't do any API call.

How do I fix this?
Things I have done:

Adding "proxy": "http://localhost:3000" and "proxy": "192.168.1.2:3000" to package.json (both doesn't work)

Changing "start" script to: "HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start" and "react-scripts start --host=0.0.0.0" (both does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you are fetching from localhost similar to this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/customers")
```

The reason proxy isn't working in the config file would be because you need to remove "http://localhost:3000" from the fetch. Otherwise, it is still pinging localhost for the api, and not using the proxy setting. So it should look like this:

```
fetch("/customers")
```

Of course, without a reproducible example, it is hard to tell if that is exactly the problem you are having.

Comment: Hello Smarticles101, I made my axios instance baseURL from: "http://localhost:3000" to "" and now it works perfectly on my phone as well. Thank you very much!